# Help with the Arduino Wire I2C Communication with MAX16826 LED Controller IC

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to read and write to this [MAX16826 LED controller evaluation board](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Maxim-Integrated/MAX16826EVKIT+?qs=LbY2dft4ljAJCiFiW%252Bs8Xg%3D%3D) through I2C. There is no specific library for this IC so I have to use the Wire library and the datasheet to try to communicate with it. My use of this library is limited and my test code doesn't seem to work. While I wait for the MAXIM tech support, I thought I'd ask here.

According to the IC datasheet, the **7-bit address is 0x58** while the **8-bit read and write addresses are 0xB1 & 0xB0 respectively**. I was able to detect the 7-bit address using the i2c_scanner example sketch but after a while, it seems to lose communications with it. Attached below is a picture of what I meant.

[image: Serial Monitor i2c scanner]

My code tries to read and write to the MAX16826's register 0x00 by following along the Wire API and the datasheet. However the results I got out of the register from Wire.requestFrom() was 255 when it should be 0. Not sure what's exactly going on. I read through the Wire API but still not sure how to detect the ack bits from the slave IC.

Here are the relevant key information from the datasheet:

[image: Read Write Format]
[image: Register Table]

Here is my Arduino test code. I did remove parts that were extra and unnecessary for simplicity purposes:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define MaxAddr 0x58        //7-bit address
#define MaxAddrRead 0xB1    //8-bit read address
#define MaxAddrWrite 0xB0   //8-bit write address
#define enPin 12            //Arduino pin for IC enable

//protoype function declarations
void basicWriteTest();
void basicReadTest();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  //enable the MAX16826 IC
  pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enPin, HIGH);
  //wait for the serial monitor to be opened
  while (!Serial);
  delay(1500);
  //function to write to register 0x00
  basicWriteTest();
}

void loop() {
  //function to write the value at register 0x00
  basicReadTest();
  delay(1500);
}

void basicWriteTest(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MaxAddrWrite);
  //write to register 0x00
  Wire.write(0x00);
  //write the value 0x00 to that register
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void basicReadTest(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MaxAddrRead);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(MaxAddrRead, 1);
  if (Wire.available() <= 1){
    uint8_t data = Wire.read();
    Serial.println("Data = " + String(data));
    
    float mV = float(316) - 1.72 * (data & 0x7F);
    float mA = mV/2.2;

    Serial.println("mV = " + String(mV));
    Serial.println("mA = " + String(mA));
  }else{
    Serial.println("Failed to get read on MAX!");
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be using the 7bit address for beginTransmission/requestFrom

Comment: @Mat how would I write the final bit for read or write then?

Comment: The library does it. Check the docs (parameter descriptions) for those two functions.

Comment: Check your pull up resistors.

Comment: @Gil I have a 10K pull up resistor on both the SDA and SCL line so I highly doubt that's the problem.

Comment: That is a bit light, try using 4.7K pull up resistors one for SCA and one for SCL I think your problem will go away. Without a schematic or knowing how long the wires are I cannot be sure. If you are operating on 3V3 go to something in the 3K range.